# Unable to print complete Binary Search Tree because my logic to iterate backwards from the lowest Node is flawed

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a program which is using for-loop to print all the elements in the BST in-order. I know that in order to do so, I need to print the left-Node, Parent Node, and then the right node. I can make such programs work when there is no for-loop involved. However, I am failing here to navigate backwards properly. In `findNext()` my logic is incorrect, because it prevents me from printing the complete tree. For  example, if I have the following tree,

```
        101
     /        \
    51        161
   /  \      /  \ 
  31   91   141   171
```

Then my output would look something like the following (when I run the code which I pasted below).

```
31 
51 
101 
161 
171
```

In the output above, I am missing the data for 91 and 141. I know why I am missing the data in these nodes ( because of `findNext()`) , but I can't figure out how to fix this issue using my logic. I am pasting the code below. I know I can probably use queues to solve this issue, but I think that's unnecessary because then I overcomplicating a simple problem.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>


struct node {
    int value;
    node * left;
    node * right;
    node * parent;//Since we are given Parent node, we can keep track of root (previous) node.

    node( int value, node * left, node * right, node * parent=NULL ) :
        value( value ), left( left ), right( right ), parent( parent ) {}
};

// Find the minimum element in the BST. This function runs as expected.
// It only runs one time to find 31 (the lowest element in BST) 
struct node * findMin( struct node *n ){    
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (n->left == NULL)
        return n;
    return findMin(n->left);
}

//This function is supposed to provide the caller with the next available node to print.
//We are trying to print the elements in-order, so findNext() should first return 51, followed
//by 91, then followed by 101 etc. However, it is not returning 91. It returns 51, 101, 161 etc.
struct node * findNext( struct node *n ) {
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (n->parent)
    {
        // Logic: Return the parent node if we are in the left node. We know we are in the left node
        // because n->parent->left == n.
        if (n->parent->left == n)  
            return n->parent;

        // Logic: Return the right node if we are in the right node. This is wrong. I am lost after this point. 
        // I wanna be able to tell that I am in the Parent node or the right node. 
        // If I am in the parent node, then I wanna return the right node. If I am in 
        // right node, then I wanna return parent's parent. 
        if (n->parent->right == n)
            return n->right;
        else
            return n->left;
    }
    else
    {
        return n->right;
    } // I know how BST works, but I honestly can't figure out how to automate this without queues. 
}

// This function can be ignored, only part of setup process.
void connectparent( node * n, node * parent ) {
    if( n ) {
        n->parent = parent;
        connectparent( n->left, n );
        connectparent( n->right, n );
    }
}
// This function can be ignored, only part of setup process.
node * constructtree() {
    node * root = new node(101,
            new node( 51, new node( 31, NULL, NULL ), new node( 91, NULL, NULL ) ),
            new node( 161, new node( 141, NULL, NULL ),new node( 171, NULL, NULL ) ) );
    connectparent( root, NULL );
    return root;
}

int main() {
    node * root = constructtree();
    for( node * n = findMin( root ); n; n = findNext( n ) ) {
        printf( "%d \n", n->value );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have comments about "This function can be ignored...".  How do you know these functions do not have bugs?  Second, the code, to me, is overcomplicated for such a task.  The canonical way to do an in-order search of a BST is simple: `void traverse(node *n) { if ( !n) return; traverse(n->left); DoSomethingWIth(n->value); traverse(n->right);}` -- The only difference in any in-order traversal is `DoSomethingWith` -- it could be print the value of `n`, write `n` to a file, whatever.

Comment: I ran gdb on this program and I can see the program is skipping some nodes because of the logic that I am using in ```findNext()```. I would prefer if the reader just focuses on the ```findNext()``` function instead of other functions like connecttree and connectParent. Also, I was given the task to fill out ```findNext()``` and ```findMin()``` and that's the only code that I wrote myself. In the past I have always followed your approach to do an in-order traversal which is a lot easier.

Comment: are you sure about your ```findNext``` signature? in particular when you "get back" to node ```n``` (after having explored one of the left or right subtree), either you want to explore its right, or explore its parent. How can you distinguish between both? To me, you would need at least the n's child (from which you call findNext) to compare it to n to know whether you come back from the left or the right

Comment: @NumbersInMyHead -- Then write your search exactly as I described.  The only difference is what you do with the nodes value.  The traversal should not change at all.  If the traverse mechanism was not broken, why did you feel a need to change it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I fail to see how your suggestion helps. NumbersInMyHead wants an iterator over tree so he can call next on the iterator. The traverse you provide does not provide such iterator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Like I mentioned, I only filled out ```findNext()``` and ```findMin()```. The rest of the code was given to me and I am not allowed to modify it.

Comment: @user753642 I think you are getting where my problem is, but I am still not following your solution (if I was allowed to change the signature of ```findNext()```). In this data structure, we are always keeping track of the parent node. Whenever I am in a node, I am unable to distinguish if the node has been traversed before or not. Can you think of a way to do that? I'd be okay to change the signature if there is  no other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution which doesn't require me to change my signature of `findNext()`.

`findNext()` would be what's shown below. If i use the code below, I am getting a complete BST with no nodes missing.

```
struct node * findNext( struct node *n ) { 
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(n->right) {
        return findMin(n->right);
    }   
    else {
        for(; n->parent; n=n->parent) {
            if(n->parent->left == n) {
                return n->parent;
            }   
        }   
        return NULL;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have an answer, I hope this information is useful. **Iterating** from anywhere in the tree can also be achieved with cookies. Would you consider using objects?

For the `Node` class, I have added a destroy function and the ability to link children automatically

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node
{
  Node *parent;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
  int value;

  Node(int value, Node *left=nullptr, Node *right=nullptr) : parent(nullptr), left(left), right(right), value(value)
  {
    if (left) { left->parent = this; }
    if (right) { right->parent = this; }
  }

  Node(const Node&) = delete;

 ~Node(void)
  {
    if (parent && (parent->left == this)) { parent->left = nullptr; }
    if (parent && (parent->right == this)) { parent->right = nullptr; }
    parent = left = right = nullptr;
    //...
    cout << "destroying node<" << value << ">...\n";
  }

  void destroy(void)
  {
    for (auto *ptr : {left, right})
    {
      if (ptr)
      {
        if (ptr->left || ptr->right) { ptr->destroy(); }
        delete ptr;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I added a simple `NodeTree` class to manage the `Nodes`.

```
struct NodeTree
{
  Node *root;

  NodeTree(Node *root=nullptr) : root(root)
  {
    //
  }

 ~NodeTree(void)
  {
    clear();
  }

  void clear(void)
  {
    if (root) { root->destroy(); delete root; root = nullptr; }
  }

  Node* bottomLeft(void)
  {
    if (root == nullptr) return nullptr;

    for (auto *ptr = root; true; ptr = ptr->left)
    {
      if (ptr->left == nullptr) { return ptr; }
    }
  }
};
```

Finally, I added a `NodeIterator` class. This object would allow you **move from any `Node` in any direction**.

```
struct NodeIterator
{
  std::list<Node*> cookie; // keeps a list of visited nodes

  NodeIterator(void) {}
  NodeIterator(const NodeIterator&) = delete;
 ~NodeIterator(void) {}

  Node* findNext(Node *ptr, int flag = 0x3)
  {
    if (ptr)
    {
      // flag:
      // 0x1 -> search upstream for unvisited nodes
      // 0x2 -> search downstream for unvisited nodes

      if ((flag <= 0) || (flag > 0x3)) flag = 0x3;

      cookie.push_back(ptr);

      for (; (ptr != nullptr); ptr = ptr->parent)
      {
        if ((flag & 0x2) && ptr->left && (std::find(cookie.begin(), cookie.end(), ptr->left) == cookie.end())) return ptr->left; // move down
        if ((flag & 0x2) && ptr->right && (std::find(cookie.begin(), cookie.end(), ptr->right) == cookie.end())) return ptr->right; // move down
        if ((flag & 0x1) && ptr->parent && (std::find(cookie.begin(), cookie.end(), ptr->parent) == cookie.end())) return ptr->parent; // move up
        if ((flag & 0x1) == 0) break; // stop, if not allowed to search upstream
      }
    }

    return nullptr;
  }
};
```

For the `main` function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  NodeTree N(new Node(101, new Node(51, new Node(31), new Node(91)), new Node(161, new Node(141), new Node(171))));

  NodeIterator iter;

  for (auto *ptr = N.bottomLeft(); (ptr != nullptr); ptr = iter.findNext(ptr))
  {
    cout << ">> " << ptr->value << '\n';
  }

  cout << "...............\n";

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
>> 31
>> 51
>> 91
>> 101
>> 161
>> 141
>> 171
...............
destroying node<31>...
destroying node<91>...
destroying node<51>...
destroying node<141>...
destroying node<171>...
destroying node<161>...
destroying node<101>...
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental bad assumption here is that `findNext` should take only one step (through one pointer).  If you consider the nodes immediately before and after the root of a deep tree (note that these are *not* the root’s children!), obviously many `parent` links must be followed to reach the root, and then one `right` and many `left` nodes must be followed to step away from it.  (In fact, that particular case is `findMin(root->right)`, which suggests that they can be combined somehow.)  With that in mind, and the recognition that the stepping up should stop when it was a step *to the right* (how would you tell?), it should be straightforward to design a correct BST stepping function.